# Checks if n elements in one array comes before n elements in another array

Tags: java, arrays, loops, comparison

Java: i want to compare 2 arrays, i want to find out if the first n entries in the array s comes before the first n entries in array t in dictionary order, in other words if n = 4 then ('b''i''n''a''r''y') is less than ('b''i''n''d'). because the 4th element of binary 'a' comes before the 4th element of bind 'd'
i'm really struggling with this

```
@Override
public boolean lessThan(char[] s, char[] t, int n) {



    for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++){


        if (s[i] > t[i]){

            return true;

        }


    }

    return false;

}
```

Comment: s[s.length-1] < t[0] would work. because the nth entry of s comes before the first entry of t[0]. No?

Comment: well if it is sorted

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: @yassin hajaj, if the first n elements of array s is less than first n elements of array t in dictionary or then the method should return true. e.g.  "binary" is less than "bind" because the 4th letter in "binary" which is "a" comes before the 4th letter in "bind" which is "d"

Comment: Please change the title into a question to clarify what you are asking. It's unclear what you're having trouble with.

Comment: Nit: The name of this method (or the logic) is wrong: this returns true if the first n chars of s is less than *or equal to* the first n chars of t.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the ASCII char of each char should work.

```
public boolean lessThan(char[] s, char[] t, int n) {
        boolean isLess = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if((int) t[i] > (int) s[i]){
                isLess = false;
            }
        }
        return isLess;
    }
```

Comment: wrong, that code doesn't determine if the first n elements of array s is less than first n elements of array t in dictionary order

Comment: sure, if the first n elements of array s is less than first n elements of array t in dictionary order then the method should return true. For example, "binary" in array s is less than "bind" in array t, because the 4th letter in "binary" which is "a" comes before the 4th letter in "bind" which is "d in dictionary order. and hence the first n elements in s is less than first n elements in t and it should return true

Comment: Nit: The name of this method (or the logic) is wrong: this returns true if the first n chars of s is less than *or equal to* the first n chars of t.

Comment: if first n char of s is less then t, isLess = true. Else isLess = false

Comment: Nit pick 2: `char` is not ASCII; It's Unicode/UTF-16. (Same as in .NET, JavaScript, …)

Comment: (Int) t[i] returns the ASCII value. That ASCII value I am comparing to find out if which letter is smaller.

Answer (score 0):

Build strings and compare them

```
return new String(s, 0, n).compareTo(new String(t, 0, n) < 0;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Andy, i can't tell you how much that line of code helped me!